# Error during deploying django app in Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Django application to Heroku. When I followed the documentation and tried the command `git push heroku master`, I am getting an `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-eyrie-25993.git'`. I searched online and tried to use git pull. But it didn't work. I also tried using `git push -f heroku master`, but still getting the same error. Is there any other way to do it? I followed this doc
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support.
Tried using the heroku dashboard, but it is giving the same error
`Building on the Heroku-18 stack !     No default language could be detected for this app. HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks !     Push failed`

Answer (score 0):

You can also deploy from your application dashboard on Heroku

Comment: And how to do that. Can you please explain?

Comment: Visit dashboard.heroku.com, then select new and create a new app, after creating the app, select connect to GitHub and search for the application, after selecting the app, you will see the option to deploy a GitHub branch.

Comment: Just now tried using the dashboard, but gives the same error again.

Comment: You can add a buildpack from the dashboard, select settings, and click on Add a buildpack

Comment: And what should be added for `static`. Do we need to add a directory named `static`

Comment: I am not certain about that

Answer (score 0):

Heroku deployment requires **requirements.txt** in the root of the repository.
Also, to run a Django app - it requires file **Procfile**

Sample content:

```
web: gunicorn your_app_name.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

You can also try to specify buildpack manually by executing:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Then if there are additional errors starting - they will be more specific

Also settings.py of your Django application should contain the following:

```
import django_heroku

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

For more details, please refer [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

Comment: I specified buildpacks. How to create Procfile

Comment: It is just a plain text file without extension with name `Procfile` you can copy-paste the gunicorn command I posted above there with any text editor